# Querying related posts to a custom taxonomy term getting results from other terms as well

Tags: php, wordpress

In my WP v6.1.1, I have a custom post type `place`, and custom taxonomy `country`. Each post can have only one custom taxonomy term selected.

With the below query, I am trying to get related posts from the specific country (Germany):

```
   // related places query
    $posts_rel_args = array(
        'post__not_in' => array($place_id), // current place post ID
        'post_type' => 'place',
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'tax_query' => array(
            'taxonomy' => 'country',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => array($cur_place_related_term_id), // valid term_id from the current pots, example = 83 (slug = germany)
        )
    );
    $posts_rel = new WP_Query($posts_rel_args);
```

When using the above query `$posts_rel->have_posts()`, posts are listed from various other countries as well, not only from Germany.

Comment: Further reading about `tax_query` found out that is an array of arrays by design. I missed that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tax_query` is an array of arrays by design. It was missing.

```
   // related places query
    $posts_rel_args = array(
        array(
        'post__not_in' => array($place_id), // current place post ID
        'post_type' => 'place',
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'tax_query' => array(
            'taxonomy' => 'country',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => array($cur_place_related_term_id), // valid term_id from the current pots, example = 83 (slug = germany)
        )
       )
    );
    $posts_rel = new WP_Query($posts_rel_args);
```